# Setting post data with a Laravel request object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to test a Laravel API endpoint and want to call it in code.

```
    $request = Request::create( $path, $method );
    $response = Route::dispatch( $request );
```

This snippet works fine for GET but I need to be able to set up POST calls too.  Setting the $method to POST works as well, but I can't find documentation detailing how to attach post data.

Any advice?

Comment: So what error message are you getting? You said setting it to POST works

Comment: Yeah it works in the sense that the request object is set to POST but I cannot find a way to attach post data to it.  So there is no error, but when I try to execute it the controller method does not receive any data to action.  I have found that $response = $this->call( $method, $path, $data ); works better and think this might be the answer actually

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, you could use `$this->call()` but you can actually do it with your current code too. If you take a look at the signature of the `Request::create()` function you can see that it takes `$parameters` as third argument:

```
public static function create($uri, $method = 'GET', $parameters = array(), $cookies = array(), $files = array(), $server = array(), $content = null)
```

And the docblock says: `The query (GET) or request (POST) parameters`

So you can simply add the data to `Request::create()`

```
$data = array('foo' => 'bar');
$request = Request::create( $path, $method, $data );
$response = Route::dispatch( $request );
```

Comment: Very handy for artisan tinker: `$request = Request::create( $path, $method, $data );`

Answer (score 5):

I've spent nearly a day trying to get this working myself for social authentication with passport and Angular front-end.

When I use the Restlet API Client to make the request I always get a successful response.
[Restlet Client Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyHS9.png)

[Restlet client response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQtce.png)

However using the following method of making internal requests always gave me an error.

```
$request = Request::create(
    '/oauth/token',
    'POST',
    [
        'grant_type' => 'social',
        'client_id' => 'your_oauth_client_id',
        'client_secret' => 'your_oauth_client_secret',
        'provider' => 'social_auth_provider', // e.g facebook, google
        'access_token' => 'access_token', // access token issued by specified provider
    ]
);

$response = Route::dispatch($request);
$content = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
if (! $response->isSuccessful()) {
    return response()->json($content, 401);
}

return response()->json([
    'content' => $content,
    'access_token' => $content['access_token'],
    'refresh_token' => $content['refresh_token'],
    'token_type' => $content['token_type'],
    'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
        $content['expires_in']
    )->toDateTimeString()
]);
```

This specific error:

```
{
    error: "unsupported_grant_type",
    error_description: "The authorization grant type is not supported by the 
    authorization server.",
    hint: "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
    message: "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
}
```

I had the feeling it has to do with the way the form data is sent in the request, so while searching for a proper way to make such internal requests in laravel I came across this sample project with a working implementation: [passport-social-grant-example](https://github.com/adaojunior/passport-social-grant-example/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php).

In summary here's how to do it:

```
$proxy = Request::create(
    '/oauth/token',
    'POST',
    [
        'grant_type' => 'social',
        'client_id' => 'your_oauth_client_id',
        'client_secret' => 'your_oauth_client_secret',
        'provider' => 'social_auth_provider', // e.g facebook, google
        'access_token' => 'access_token', // access token issued by specified provider
    ]
);

return app()->handle($proxy);
```

Hope this helps.